# Sketch the solid described by $r^2 \le z \le 8-r^2$, $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$, and $r \le z \le 2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Sketch the solid described by the following inequalities.
>
> 1. $r^2 \le z \le 8-r^2$
> 2. $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$, and $r \le z \le 2$

I'm not sure how to approach this. I read the section on cylindrical coordinates, and I know how to plot points in cylindrical, and switch from rectangle to polar, but I don't know what to do with this. It seems like plotting points would take forever, and there should be some faster way.

Comment: So, you're asking for a computer program or what?

Comment: Are you aware of the cone: $z  =r$? If yes then the second inequality is just a piece of cake.

Comment: i figured there was some intuitive way to identify it or sketch it without having to plot a ton of points

Comment: @MathLover yes .

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to have some intuition on the shapes of common functions in cylindrical coordinates.

One thing I find the most helpful is equations relating $r$ and $z$. Since there is no $\theta$ relation, the functions $z = z(r)$ all describe rotationally symmetric surfaces. The idea is if you can plot $z$ vs. $r$ in 2D, the 3D result is that curve revolved around the $z$ axis. If you've done anything similar to surfaces and volumes of revolution in single-variable calculus, this is the same idea. F

or example, functions of the form

$$ z = ar^2 + b $$

Looks like a parabola on the plane, so in 3D it is a paraboloid

[image]

Functions of the form
$$ z = ar $$

are diagonal lines revolved around the $z$-axis, so they're shaped like a cone.

[image]

When these functions are combined with limits on $\theta$ (like in your second example), it restricts the angle of revolution. So $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$ on makes a quarter revolution in the first quadrant, and in effect looks like quarter cone.

Comment: ok, I understand the basic shapes, but I'm not sure how to translate those to  8−r^2  and  r≤z≤2